# Open a file in C++

Tags: c++

I need to open a file but without asking twice for it.

```
std::string open_file(){
std::string file_name{};

std::cout << "Please enter a file name: ";
std::cin >> file_name;

return file_name;
}
```

That is my function to open a file. But when I want to work with the opened file in another function I have something like this:

```
std::string file_name;
file_name = open_file();
std::ifstream file(file_name);
```

Which works but it asks me again to enter the name of the file I want to open.

Comment: Instead of asking for file name in `open_file`, ask before calling that and pass the name as an argument.

Comment: Looking carefully, the function `open_file` do not actually open any files. The naming is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual question is not about opening files, but about the scope of variables in your program. It is sound advice, based on enough problems in software to limit the scope of variables as mucu as possible and you have done that. However, the scope still needs to be wide enough to have useful programs.

The opposite would be to declare all your variables globally, maybe even together in one variables-file and that would have solved your problem nicely. However, while most student-assignments are small enough, so you don't run into strange bugs, normal successful programs are too complex and soon bugs will be too gard to solve because everything is mixed.

Unfortunately, there is not one clear answer where to declare your filename, but it shouldn't be that gard either. It could be in one of the calling functions or in the class. You could even make the filename persistent (file or database) so you don't have to ask it every time you start the program.

Answer (score 0):

> it asks me again to enter the name of the file I want to open

There are many ways to deal with the File name and not having it to pass to the function. So you just have to write the Name of the file only once - when you open it.
What to pass to `std::fstring` is defined in the standard and you would have to use c++ polymorphism or overloading/virtual and write your own std::fstring class in order to change that.

Global variables should be avoided because global variables pollute the global namespace.

I came up with a few examples that should help you find the Solution fitting for you. Sure there are many more ways to do it, those are just a few:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//declaring makro for filename. Executed on compiletime
#define FILENAME "FileName.txt"

struct name{
  std::string filename{"FileName3.txt"};
  int number{120};
};

//you always have to pass the address of the file
void functionWrite(std::fstream &file)
{
  name Name;
  file.open(Name.filename, std::ios::out);
  int number{Name.number};
  file << number;
  file.close();
}
void functionRead(std::fstream &file)
{
  //Clear errors and reset read cursor
  file.clear();
  name Name;
  file.open(Name.filename, std::ios::in);
  int number{};
  file >> number;
  std::cout << number << '\n';
  file.close();
}

void functionWrite2(std::fstream &file)
{
  file.open(FILENAME, std::ios::out);
  int number{40};
  file << number;
  file.close();
}

//overloading functionWrit2
void functionWrite2(std::fstream &file, std::string filename)
{
  file.open(filename, std::ios::out);
  int number{80};
  file << number;
  file.close();
}


void functionRead2(std::fstream &file)
{
  //Clear errors and reset read cursor
  file.clear();
  file.open(FILENAME, std::ios::in);
  int number{};
  file >> number;
  std::cout << number << '\n';
  file.close();
}
//overloading functionWrit2
void functionRead2(std::fstream &file,std::string filename)
{
  //Clear errors and reset read cursor
  file.clear();
  file.open(filename, std::ios::in);
  int number{};
  file >> number;
  std::cout << number << '\n';
  file.close();
}

int main()
{
  std::fstream open_file;

  functionWrite(open_file);
  functionRead(open_file);

  functionWrite2(open_file);
  functionRead2(open_file);

  functionWrite2(open_file,"FileName2.txt");
  functionRead2(open_file,"FileName2.txt");


  std::cout << "Press RETURN to continue";
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```